# Notepad++: можно ли настроить обозреватель классов, функций?

Tags: php, notepad++

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность настроить эксплорер классов,функций (PHP) в могущественном Notepad++ ?

Гуглом умею пользоватся. Но там не нашел то что искал.

Те кто пользуются этим редактором ,думаю поймут меня.

Если есть - то как ? Хотелось бы как в Netbeanse, чтобы удобное навигация было  по классам,функциям.
[image]

Comment: интересует тоже самое под Sublime text 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ Plugins
A plugin to improve Notepad++
http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Function%20List/

[image]

Comment: да, это походить , а нет ли эксплорер классов+функциями ?

Comment: @Vfvtnjd там в xml файле можно как-то и классы добавить. А вот как - не знаю, не пробовал.

Comment: А он работает? У меня че-то при его использовании notepad крашится...

Comment: @ВОРОН,да работает.

![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/GJm5agy.jpg